# uploading a file at the same time saving another data's from database codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

i have a question regarding with this situation
I have two forms which consist of #1 Form is an image uploader form and the #2 Form is consist of user data which i want to fire with a one button only using ajax.

Here my problem is about passing the values. How can i make this `var formData = new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]);`

and
 `#frm_patientreg`

to be something like this: `$('#form-upload, #frm_patientreg').serialize(),`

Here is my ajax:

```
var inputFile = $('input[name=file]');
//    var uploadURI = $('#form-upload').attr('action');
    var fileToUpload = inputFile[0].files[0];
    if(fileToUpload != 'undefine') {
            var formData = new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/addpatient",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("Successfully Added");
                    $('#frm_patientreg')[0].reset();
                }
            });
    }
    else {
      alert("No File Selected");
    }
```

JSFIDDLE :https://jsfiddle.net/ny3rvowo/1/

Comment: try enctype="multipart/form-data" to form attribute

Comment: @RahulMeshram where would i put that sir ?

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" ......>

Comment: sir i saw the problem with this. var formData = new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]);
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/addpatient",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("Successfully Added");
                    $('#frm_patientreg')[0].reset();
                }
            });

Comment: correct this $('input[name="file"]'); and check the output with console, can you give me sample example in jsfiddle ?

Comment: @RahulMeshram i already spotted the problem sir.. i edited my question please check it out. thats my real problem

Comment: var inputFile = $('input[name=file]'); change name of element to something else,
    if(fileToUpload != 'undefine') { change to     if(fileToUpload != 'undefined') {

Comment: can you please answer sir ? to clearly answer a code ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/swapper8/ny3rvowo/ , please prepare scenario on jsfiddle as in I am unable to debug

Comment: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/ny3rvowo/1/